# How to get all text between <strong> </strong> in MS word to turn Bold using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically I want to transform the text in between the  tags into bold. This text will always be in the comments. The current code doesnt do anything.
I am not really sure if this code makes any sense at all, but I usually use VBA for Excel and word seems to be a bit trickier.

```
Sub Bold()
    Dim eCom As Comment
    Dim iFound As Integer
    Dim rbold As Range
    Dim iDot As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim aDoc As Document
    Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
    flag = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each eCom In ActiveDocument.Comments

        iFound = InStr(eCom.Range.Text, "<strong>")
        iDot = 0
        If iFound > 0 Then

            iDot = InStrRev(eCom.Range, "</") - iFound + 1
            Set rbold = aDoc.Range(Start:=eCom.Range.Start + iFound, End:=eCom.Range.Start + InStrRev(eCom.Range, "<"))
            rbold.Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
        End If

    Next eCom
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code work?  Is there an error when you run it?  What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Code doesnt turn anything into bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.  First, it appears that the Comment Ranges do not use the same numbering as the document ranges.  So

```
 Set rbold = aDoc.Range(Start:=eCom.Range.Start + iFound, End:=eCom.Range.Start + InStrRev(eCom.Range, "<"))
```

is not actually the range in the comments, it is instead a range in the document starting with the place in the comment that has the strong html tag.

Second, even if this was working, it would start the bolding in the wrong place, starting with "strong>"

Third, there's no reason to select the range, just set it to bold.

This code will do what you want (I commented out a line as I couldn't figure out what it was supposed to do):

```
Sub Bold()
    Dim eCom As Comment
    Dim iFound As Integer
    Dim rbold As Range
    Dim iDot As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim aDoc As Document
    Dim newCom As Comment
    Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
    flag = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each eCom In ActiveDocument.Comments

        iFound = InStr(eCom.Range.Text, "<strong>")
        iDot = 0
        If iFound > 0 Then

            'iDot = InStrRev(eCom.Range, "</") - iFound + 1
            Set rbold = eCom.Range
            rbold.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-(Len(rbold) - InStrRev(rbold, "</") + 1)
            rbold.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=iFound + Len("<strong>") - 1
            rbold.Bold = True

        End If

    Next eCom
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```